# How to save changes to a bootable USB Kali Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb, kali-linux

I have recently made a bootable usb with Linux Kali on it, and I have been using it for a while now but it becomes very annoying when I have to log into everything every time I boot into Kali...

So my question is : 
How to save changes to this usb!?
I don't have to be able to install software or anything... 
If I can at least save .txt files then I'm happy

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to boot it in Persistence Mode http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence

Comment: @YisroelTech Quote what needs done to enable persistence mode and that's an answer

Answer (score 1):

To enable persistence you have to:
1.) Create a new partition with ext3/ext4 and call it "persistence" (e.g. with gparted)
2.) create a new mountpoint: `mkdir -p /mnt/kaliusb`
3.) mount the partition from 1.) to this mountpoint: `mount /dev/sdc2 /mnt/kaliusb`
4.) create the persistence.conf file in it: `echo "/ union" > /mnt/kaliusb/persistence.conf`
5.) unmount the partition: `umount /dev/sdc2`
6.) reboot and select the "with persistence" option at the kali boot screen

After that all your changes are saved.
Refer to: https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence for details and **how to make an encrypted persitent partition*** (it's really easy and nice explained (kudos to these guys)

*you can do all this while runnng in the kali-live environment on the same usb stick (refer to: https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install) - that assures, that you have all tools like "cryptsetup" in place